# AngularJS router - parent controller loads when child is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having strange results working with AngualarJS states. Here is app code:

```
/* myApp module */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: "home",
    template: '<div ui-view><h3>Home</h3><a ui-sref="home.child({reportID:1})">Child</a></div>',
    params: { reportID: null },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.homeCtrlVar = "home";
        console.log("Home controller loaded");
    }
}).state('home.child', {
    template: '<div><h3>Child</h3><a ui-sref="home">Back</a></div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.childCtrlVar = "child";
        console.log("Child controller loaded");
    }
});
})

 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
 console.log("MainCtrl initialized!");

 $state.go("home");
 });
```

And main page:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <h2>My app</h2>

<div ui-view></div>
```

What's happening is that as long as there parameters for the home state and reportID value doesn't match between a parameter being sent and the state default the home controller is loaded when I click on Child. Can someone please explain why that's happening?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxrSd/19/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated code which works as you expect it to:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: "home",
        template: '<div ui-view><h3>Home</h3><a ui-sref="home.child({reportID:1})">Child</a></div>',       
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.homeCtrlVar = "home";
            console.log("Home controller loaded");
        }
    }).state('home.child', {
        url: "/:reportID",
        params: { reportID: null },
        template: '<div><h3>Child</h3><a ui-sref="home">Back</a></div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.childCtrlVar = "child";
            console.log("Child controller loaded");
        }
    });
})
```

Problem with your approach:
specifying `params reportID` in `home` state instead of `home.child` state.

When user clicks on `home.child({ reportId: 1})` it should load `home.child`, which is fine, and was working with old approach.
However, If you take notice, as you click on `home.child({ reportId: 1})`, you are sending new parameter `reportID`(old value was null). `reportID` belongs to `home` state, hence its controller is also loaded.

Note that `url: "/:reportID"` in state `home.child` is optional.